# DateFormat pattern "dd/MM/yyyy" accept wrong months

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a string format date with "dd/MM/yyyy" (pattern Brazil)

But in my code when convert in date, accept a wrong months.

```
    *String str = "01/15/2021"; 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dt = df.parse(str);        
    System.out.println(dt);*
```

The result is: Tue Mar 01 00:00:00 BRT 2022

How invalidate this ?

Comment: `df.setLenient(valse);`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
df.setLenient(false);
```

But please look at other date types like LocalDate or ZonedDate. Much easier down the road ;)

Answer (score 1):

Modern solution uses *java.time* classes, never `Date` or `Calendar`.

By default, `LocalDate` parsing is strict rather than lenient. Trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
String input = "01/15/2021" ;
try {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … handle faulty input here …
}
```

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` gives us a formatter with smart resolver style. So the code will still accept for instance `31/02/2021` (and interpret it as 2021-02-28). For better validation use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ).withResolverStyle( ResolverStyle.STRICT )`.